# phantomjs-node + lab (test utility from hapijs) + test coverage

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, hapi.js

I am using [phantomjs-node](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node) and it is, unfortunately, not playing well with [lab](https://github.com/hapijs/lab)'s test coverage stuff. When I run `lab -t 100`, it is trying to inject `__$$labCov` into the function passed to `page.evalute()`. However, that function is not executed in the context of the code in which it appears. It is executed in the context of the phantom browser.

So, in my code that is being tested, if I have this in the midst of my PhantomJS code:

```
page.evaluate(
    function () { return 'foo'; }, 
    function (result) {
                // Do something with result here
                ph.exit();
    }
);
```

In the second function, `result` should be the string "foo". And that's what happens when I just run the code. But if I run it via `lab -t 100`, it is `null` and I get "phantom stdout: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: __$$labCov".

Is there a way to tell lab, "Hey, I know this one line looks like code that yo
u want to make sure gets run, but really, don't worry about this little function here, it's not for you."?

Alternately, is there a way I can access `__$$labCov` so that I can make it available to the sandboxed function? Phantom let's you do it like this:

```
page.evaluate(
    function (__$$labCOv) { return 'foo'; }, 
    function (result) {
                // Do something with result here
                ph.exit();
    },
    __$$labCov
);
```

But that doesn't work because I don't have access to `__$$labCov`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lab has a little undocumented feature where you can mark a section of the code for coverage exclusion. It is used by the lab coverage code itself (since lab uses lab to test lab). Just surround your code with `$lab:coverage:off$` and `$lab:coverage:on$`.

https://github.com/hapijs/lab/blob/master/lib/coverage.js#L240-L261